# how to restrict the droppable in jquery drag/drop?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

is it possible to restrict the droppable area.

I want my draggable to revert back if its not completely in the draggable.
here is the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/jWNkh/22/
 I want the draggable to  revert back if its not in the drag1 div.

jquery:

```
    $("#drag").draggable({
             revert:'invalid',
             cursor:'move',
             appendTo: 'body',
             containment    : 'document',

             helper     : 'clone'
        });
        $("#drop").droppable({         
            accept:'#drag',
            drop:  dropFunction,                              

            });
```

How can i limit the area ? any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `accept` property on the droppable options, aswell as the `tolerance` property (read more on the [tolerance property here)](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-tolerance). The `tolerance` property defines if the element has to just be 50% inside of the droppable div, or if it has to be completely inside. If you want it to only accept it if it's completely inside, you set the `tolerance` to `fit`.

It is shown in [this fiddle (an updated version of yours)](http://jsfiddle.net/jWNkh/25/)

```
$('#drop').droppable({ accept: "#drag", tolerance: "fit"});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want just drag into drop1, just set droppable in drop1 div

```
$('#drop1').droppable({

});
```